# SQL - HAVING (execution vs structure)

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I'm a beginner, studying on my own... please help me to clarify something about a query: I am working with a soccer database and trying to answer this question: list all seasons with an avg goal per `Match` rate of over 1, in `Match`s that didn’t end with a draw;

The right query for it is:

```
select season,round((sum(home_team_goal+away_team_goal) *1.0) /count(id),3) as ratio

from match

where home_team_goal != away_team_goal

group by season 

having  ratio > 1
```

I don't understand 2 things about this query:

1. Why do I *1.0? why is it necessary?
2. I know that the execution in SQL is by this order:

   from

   where

   group

   having

   select

So how does this query include: having ratio>1 if the "ratio" is only defined in the "select" which is executed AFTER the HAVING? 
Am I confused? 
Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 3):

1. The multiplication is added as a typecast to convert INT to FLOAT because by default sum of ints is int and the division looses decimal places after dividing 2 ints.
2. HAVING. You can consider HAVING as WHERE but applied to the query results. Imagine the query is executed first without HAVING and then the HAVING condition is applied to result rows leaving only suitable ones.

In you case you first select grouped data and calculate aggregated results and then skip unnecessary results of aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

the *1.0 is used for its ".0" part so that it tells the system to treat the expression as a decimal, and thus not make an integer division which would cut-off the decimal part (eg 1 instead of 1.33).

About the second part: select being at the end just means that the last thing
to be done is showing the data. Hoewever, assigning an alias to a calculated field is being done, you could say, at first priority. Still, I am a bit doubtful; I am almost certain field aliases cannot be used in the where/group by/having in, say, sql server.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am working with SQLite and I tried running the code - it works...that's exactly what I didn't get, so apparently (I run a search on it and also tried running it on a SQL optimizer) we can:-)

Comment: OK, I learnt something too: that SQLite has useable field aliases.

Answer (score 0):

There is no *order of execution* of a SQL query.  SQL is a *descriptive* language not a *procedural* language.  A SQL query describes the result set that the query is producing.  The SQL engine can execute it however it likes.  In fact, most SQL engines compile the query into a directed acyclic graph, which looks nothing like the original query.

What you are referring to might be better phrased as the "order of interpretation".  This is more simply described by simple rules.  Column aliases can be used in the `ORDER BY` clause in any database.  They cannot be used in the `FROM`, `WHERE`, or `GROUP BY` clauses.  Some databases -- such as SQLite -- allow them to be referenced in the `HAVING` clause.

As for the `* 1.0`, it is because some databases -- such as SQLite -- do integer arithmetic.  However, the logic that you want is probably more simply expressed as:

```
round((avg(home_team_goal + away_team_goal * 1.0), 3)
```